# How can i print data in a file using 2 threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i need to print some data in a file using 2 threads that run alternative, one for odd index, and the other for even index. The data i have is stored in this array, cursuri = new ArrayList(), that is created from

```
    String nume;
    String descriere;
    Profesor profu;
    Set <Student> studenti;
    int[] note;
```

The data i need is saved in studenti, and this is what i tried so far:

```
public String[] studentiEven(ArrayList<Curs> c)
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {
            for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++)
            {
                String[] x= new String[3];
                int nr=0;
                for(Student s:c.get(i).studenti)
                {
                    while(nr%2==1)
                    {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    nr++;
                    notify();
                    x[0]=s.nume;
                    x[1]=s.prenume;
                    x[2]=s.grupa;
                    return x;
                
                }
                
            }
            String[] y=new String[3];
            return y;
        }
    }
    
    public String[] studentiOdd(ArrayList<Curs> c)
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {
            for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++)
            {
                String[] x= new String[3];
                int nr=0;
                for(Student s:c.get(i).studenti)
                {
                    while(nr%2==0)
                    {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    nr++;
                    notify();
                    x[0]=s.nume;
                    x[1]=s.prenume;
                    x[2]=s.grupa;
                    return x;
                
                }
            }
            String[] y=new String[3];
            return y;
        }
    }
```

Those being 2 functions, and in the main i tried to write:

```
 try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("studenti555.txt");
            
        final String[] a = new String[3];
            Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run()
                  {
                        a[0]=c.studentiEven(c.cursuri)[0];
                        a[1]=c.studentiEven(c.cursuri)[1];
                        a[2]=c.studentiEven(c.cursuri)[2];  
                        try {
                            myWriter.write(a[0]);
                            myWriter.write(',');
                            myWriter.write(a[1]);
                            myWriter.write(' ');
                            myWriter.write(a[2]);
                            myWriter.write('\n');
                            
                            
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("eroare");
                        }
                  }
                  
                  
              }
                      );
            Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run()
                  {
                        a[0]=c.studentiOdd(c.cursuri)[0];
                        a[1]=c.studentiOdd(c.cursuri)[1];
                        a[2]=c.studentiOdd(c.cursuri)[2];   
                        try {
                            myWriter.write(a[0]);
                            myWriter.write(',');
                            myWriter.write(a[1]);
                            myWriter.write(' ');
                            myWriter.write(a[2]);
                            myWriter.write('\n');
                            
                            
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("eroare");
                        }
                  }
                  
                  
              }
            
                      );
              t1.start();
              t2.start();   
         myWriter.close();
        }catch(Exception e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            System.out.print("teapa frate \n"); 
        }
```

I tried to debug it, but it didn't go through the catch exception or anything, could you guys please help me out?

Comment: So what happens when you run this? Your question includes the notion that it does _not_ result in an exception being thrown. So, what does it do?

Comment: It just runs forever, if i try and open the output file it tells me that it's being used by another app,and therefore it's empty, i think somewhere there is a loop

Comment: FYI: Your instructor wants you to do that so that you will learn something about coordinating the activity of different threads. But note! It's a genuinely _Bad Idea_ to make two threads "take turns" like that, and it's probably a bad idea to let two threads write the same file. Don't think of this assignment as an example of something you should ever do in any "real" program.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In this case, shall i try to do a single function that will be called by two threads? I didn't think of this

Comment: _i think somewhere there is a loop_ Not a loop. I think you have a [deadlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use semaphores to do this task

by setting odd semaphore and even semaphore to 1 and 0 respectively, at the beginning when both threads try to acquire the semaphore only odd semaphore let the thread to pass because it's initialized with 1. this way guarantees that the odd thread run before the even thread.

```java
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("./text.txt");
        Semaphore oddSem = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore evenSem = new Semaphore(0);
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

for odd thread, at first line try to acquire the oddSem and after getting one item from the list release the evenSem. this way even thread can now proceed.

```java
        Runnable oddWriter = () -> {
            Object object;
            do {
                acquire(oddSem);
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    evenSem.release();
                    break;
                }
                object = list.remove(0);
                evenSem.release();
                String value = String.format("%s %s\n" , "Odd Thread:",object.toString());
                writeToFile(fileWriter, value);
            } while (true);
        };
```

for the even thread do the opposite

```java
        Runnable evenWriter = () -> {
            Object object;
            do {
                acquire(evenSem);
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    oddSem.release();
                    break;
                }
                object = list.remove(0);
                oddSem.release();
                String value = String.format("%s %s\n" , "Even Thread:",object.toString());
                writeToFile(fileWriter, value);
            } while (true);
        };
```

and finally, start threads

```java
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(oddWriter);
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(evenWriter);

        oddThread.start();
        evenThread.start();

        try {
            oddThread.join();
            evenThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: it may seem like an odd question, but do i open the file writer and then start the threads?

Comment: yes, there is slightly a small potential that writing happens before initializing FileWriter. In this situation, the program throws NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

```
 t1.start();
 t2.start();   
 myWriter.close();
```

you close myWriter while t1 and t2 are running
try with

```
 t1.start();
 t2.start();  
 t1.join();
 t2.join(); 
 myWriter.close();
```

Another problem is that both function studentiEven and studentiOdd call wait();. This stops execution till some other thread call notify() but there is no thread that call notify();

Notice also that
final String[] a = new String[3];
is shared between t1 and t2 and this is not threadsafe.

Comment: It still won't print anything in the output file, but i understand my mistake there

Comment: try flushing your writer at the end of writing a record and also try synchronizing your writer by calling synchronized(myWriter) {... }

Comment: I managed to do the task, but instead of printing to a file i printed to a console, i will further try and complete the task

Comment: I am sorry for asking, but don't both threads contain a notify before the return?

Comment: @KensoFD yes but execution stops with wait() few lines before and notify() is never called